# Best way to get the Fractional Part of a Number

Tags: c++, decimal, modulo, fractions, fmodf

Given `const auto foo = 13.42` I would like to get the numbers fractional part, so **.42**

I'm leaning toward just using [`fmod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fmod) like: `fmod(foo, 1.0)`

But I could also just do `foo / static_cast<int>(foo) - 1.0` Or perhaps some other mystical method.

Would there be a motivation for me to not simply use `fmod`?

Comment: Possibly just `auto fraction = foo - static_cast<int>(foo);`

Comment: `fmod` works pretty good, and it is easy to understand, too.

Comment: @Carl Derp. Should have seen that coming.

Comment: @JonathanMee On GCC it seems the fmod approach is really slow compared to the other two: [QuickBench](http://quick-bench.com/dbPDeaWHDnyGKvqmNGtRngOkJkw)

Comment: @Carl That is an awesome website.  I'm adding that to my bookmarks.

Comment: @NathanOliver Yep, really good site for quick benchmarks that you can share with a link. Uses Google Benchmark under the hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways I can think of, either a cast or rounding down with `std::floor`

```
int main()
{    
    const auto foo = 13.53;

    auto firstWay = foo - static_cast<long long>(foo);  // Truncating via cast and subtracting

    auto otherWay = foo - std::floor(foo); // Rounding down and subtracting

    return 0;
}
```

Quick Bench Result shows the `fmod` approach as the slowest option by far, and the cast as the fastest: [QuickBench](http://quick-bench.com/eXf25EKAheEIs0fr6G7Lic0CLPk)

Comment: I much prefer the second version.  The first could blow up as a double can store a number larger than what can be held in an `int`.

Comment: You should probably cast that to `long` instead of `int`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Would the `floor` method be preferable to `fmod` then?

Comment: @Ron Even `long` isn't right as `sizeof(long)` can equal `sizeof(int)`

Comment: `Long long` then

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm not sure.  It can probably be implemented cheaper/faster than `fmod` but I'd benchmark to find out.

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe `long long` should be sufficient as even a `long double` uses that in most implementations as it's mantissa.

Comment: @JonathanMee if you're going to hard code a type then `long long` should be okay.  I'm hesitant though as I'm pretty sure there is nothing stopping double from being larger than 64bits.

Comment: @NathanOliver You mean nothing stopping a `long double` from having a larger mantissa than a `long long` right? I thought a `double` was always 64-bits?

Comment: A type is never always a certain amount of bits. The only guarantee is that they are sized a certain way relative to the other types. See the standard for more details.

Comment: @JonathanMee The relavant standardies is *There are three floating-point types: float, double, and long double. The type double provides at least as much precision as float, and the type long double provides at least as much precision as double.*  AFAIK there is no size requirement for `double` besides what I just quoted and it needs to be able to store the value `1e+37`.  That means you can have a 128 bit double and be standard compliant.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Good catch, that is more in line with what GCC yielded. I'll update with your link.

Comment: @NathanOliver: There are requirements on `double` beyond what you've quoted. For example, `double` has to provide at least 10 decimal digits of precision, where `float` only has to provide `6`. Most easily found in the C standard, section 5.2.4.2.2/11.